# get chrome version in terminal in mac

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, google-chrome

I wrote some script in Linux which adapts CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION and CHROME_VERSION before running e2e, but I found that this script doesn't work for mac\windows because I use `google-chrome --product-version` command.
this is my script:

```
CHROME_VERSION=$(google-chrome --product-version | grep -oE "[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,5}")
CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=$(curl "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_${CHROME_VERSION}")
webdriver-manager clean && webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome $CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION
```

how do i convert it to run with mac os and run it as .exe?

i wanna do something like this:

```
   case "$(uname -s)" in
       Darwin)
         CHROME_VERSION= expression
         ;;
    
       Linux)
         CHROME_VERSION=$(google-chrome --product-version | grep -oE "[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,5}")
         ;;
    
       *)
         echo 'Other OS'
         ;;
    esac

CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=$(curl "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_${CHROME_VERSION}")
webdriver-manager clean && webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome $CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `PlistBuddy`:

```sh
zrzka@hyrule ~ % /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy \
  -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" \
  /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/Info.plist
84.0.4147.105
```

Add this to your script:

```sh
CHROME_VERSION=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/Info.plist)
```

It assumes that the Google Chrome browser is installed.